# Connect to a virtual machine via IPv6

Tags: virtualbox, ipv6

On my Ubuntu 11.04 host I've installed VirtualBox with a OpenSuse 11.4 client. After installing Apache2 in the VM I was not able to connect via IPv6 (with Firefox) to the installed HTTP-server. In the VM itself the connection with http://[::1] is possible.

Any advice?

Comment: If it was IPv4 would it be an issue?

Comment: I need to test something with IPv6. An IPv4 connection from the host is no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are connecting to the right address. If you use link-local addresses in `fe80::`, don't forget the scope identifier (on Linux - the interface name). If you are using "Bridged networking" on Ubuntu's `eth0`, you would need to add `%eth0` to the address:

`fe80::2e69:8a08%eth0`

(Similar for `vboxnet0`, `tap0`, or whatever you have. Note that VirtualBox doesn't support IPv6 over bridged wireless interfaces.)

Also try Wireshark or `tcpdump` to find out if the packets actually reach the VM.